# Coordinates of groups in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, export, svg, xml

I use Inkscape as a UI designer. I want to export each group as a single SVG using the python parser and Inkscape command line renderer but I have problems with the coordinates of each object.

For example I have a **group** which is a complete window. Inside this group we have another **group** (for example the *close* button) that includes a path, a rectangle and an ellipse.

And the parser create tree of folders depending on `<g></g>`.
When the parser "sees" the `<g></g>` then it creates a folder named `<group ID>` and goes deeper until it encounters `<g root_img="true"></g>`. Everything between `<g....></g>` is treated as separate SVG and calls Inkscape command line to render it, and save it as `*<group ID>*.png`.

This is what I have.

```
[folder]Window
    [image]close_btn.png
    [image]title_bar.png
    [folder]Products_list
        [image]product_belt1.png
        [image]product_belt3.png
        [image]product_belt2.png
    [folder]Advanced_options_window
        [image]hide_btn.png
        [image]title_aow_bar.png
        [folder]Options
            [image]opt1.png
            [image]opt2.png
            [image]opt3.png
```

I want the coordidnates values, for instance:

```
close_btn 1250, 10
title_bar 0, 0
product_belt1.png 150, 150
```

But how do I get the absolute coordinates of each group?

**EDIT: It is possible to make a plug-in which I add additional arguments[x=150, y=120] to all groups in XML?**

Answer (score 1):

**Not solution but part of it, idea**

**1 way «semi-automatic»**
Place tranparent 1px rectangle with *mark-color #f1f2f300* in left-top corner of group and get coordinates of *mark-object* by parser.

**2 way «automatic»**
As I understand it needs absolute coordinate from top-left corner, such as the size of document 1000x1000 pixels document, the root-group (height=100px) at the bottom left corner, then she has the coordinates x = 0 and y = 900. Root-group have subgroup and she has same coordinates. Or need a subgroup relative coordinates? Example root-group(0,900) subgroup (0x0)?

If you need only the absolute coordinates here easier — parse group. Compares the coordinates of objects within a group, we need an object with the smallest (x,y) coordinates. This is the position of the group.

But a little more complicated when inkscape added parameter like *transform="translate(0,-100)"*. It appears when the group made a duplicate and change the position of the group. Here it is necessary to make additions and complicate the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar a few years ago. After exploring many different options for parsing SVG files I ended up with using html/javascript. Back then I traversed the SVG file using jQuery but I'm sure there are better libraries available today (and it could be a good idea to use a [headless browser](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)).

Once you know which element you want you can call [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the absolute coordinates of it.